# Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I got following error while `apt-get update`

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/fb4097adcf683477b8870a1e205779221cb204fbe03919ce887c21797c9c800d  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/c527e281bab37365996fe61f485bf4c24687700408e5b8c926cfe11878a70b12  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/5b256f30702a00d8b04f3bd91129b6ebd584639eb7e3577bcb98444574de514f  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Suggest me How to fix this.

Comment: @RoVo I tried, but still same

Comment: what did you try? there are a lot of useful answers.